# Using JDBI @BindBean with AutoValue

Tags: java, reflection, jdbi, auto-value

**TLDR;**
The JDBI `@BindBean` annotation generates an `IllegalAccessException` with AutoValue generated types because the generated types are package private and by default can't be accessed by default using reflection.

Is JDBI inflexible or is there a workaround via AutoValue? (Full questions below)

**Quick Background**

I'm attempting to use the JDBI `@BindBean` annotation with a type whose source is generated using AutoValue.

```
package com.example;

@AutoValue
public abstract class Foo {
  public String getBar();
}
```

The issue is that the generated code looks like:

```
package com.example;

@AutoValue
class AutoValue_Foo extends Foo {
  private final String bar;

  @Override
  public String getBar() {
    return this.bar;
  }

  // toString, equals, hashCode
}
```

Notice the class is package private!

Now if I attempt to use `@BindBean`, for example:

```
@SqlQuery("select * from baz where bar = :foo.bar")
Condition find(@BindBean("foo") Foo foo);
```

Because `AutoValue_Foo` is package private, and `BindBeanFactory` uses reflection, if an attempt is made to call `find` with an `AutoValue_Foo` type, the result is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: ... can not access a member of class com.example.Foo with modifiers "public"
```

The relevant JDBI code is [here](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/e206c5681a68a5887beaecd71781dd8584b54332/src/main/java/org/skife/jdbi/v2/sqlobject/BindBeanFactory.java#L48).  I understand from a Java reflection perspective, this could be resolved using `setAccessible(true)` but that would require a PR to JDBI.

**So the questions are as follow:**

1. Is there a way to restructure my code where I can bind a `Foo` of
       type `AutoValue_Foo` using `@BindBean` without creating a new JDBI
       mapper?
2. Is there a way to have `@AutoValue` generate classes that are
      `public`.  I understand why this would generally not be desirable
      (push people to use the interface and not the implementation).
3. Is the `BindBeanFactory` too inflexible?  Should it utilize
         `setAccessible(true)` on methods that are otherwise available
         outside of their originating package?

Comment: You could use Lombok's `@Data` (https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) instead of `@AutoValue`. It generates the boilerplate inside your class, instead of making an implementation type. Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's working great for me.

Comment: @Jorn interesting to know Lombok works.  I'm unfortunately locked into AutoValue but this may be useful for other engineers who have more flexibility.

Comment: Please submit a PR to JDBI. I will shepherd it through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 2.71 of JDBI will include the ability to specify a type token to `@BindBean` using the `type` field.  This type token will allow for specifying the type used to make the reflective call against the provided argument.

`@SqlQuery("select * from baz where bar = :foo.bar")
Condition find(@BindBean(value="foo", type=Foo.class) Foo foo);`

Using this technique you can eliminate the `IllegalAccessException` described above.

Comment: will this also work for records which have no getBar() but a bar()